# Good approach for training a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a neural network model to differentiate the orange and pomegranate.
In the training dataset, the background of the object (for both orange and pomegranate) is same and constant. But while testing, the background of the object is different than what I trained with.

So my first doubt is,

> Is it good approach to train a model with **one background** (suppose white background) and test with
>   **another background** (suppose grey background)?.

Second, I trained the object with different position and the same background. Since the theory says that position doesn't matter for convolution, it has ability to recognise the object placed at anywhere, because anyhow, after convolution, the dimension of the activation map decreases and the depth increases.

So my second doubt is,

> Is it necessary or good approach to keep **the object at different position** while training
>   the model?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good approach to train a model with **one background** (suppose white background) and test with
>   **another background** (suppose grey background)?.

When training a neural network, it is important to shuffle the dataset you are using and split the dataset to training and testing sets. The reason why you need to shuffle the data, is in order for your model to see all types of samples in the training set so the moment it is exposed to new unseen data, it can reflect it over the previously seen data. In the example you mentioned above, it is important to shuffle the data due to the fact that there are different background colors which can effect the prediction of the model. Therefore both the training and the testing set need to have both background colors in order for your model to give good predictions.

> Is it necessary or good approach to keep **the object at different position** while training
>   the model?

It is indeed better to train your model with objects in different positions due to the fact it can bring your model to predict more types of oranges or pomegranates. Note that if you are using different positions for the object you are trying to predict, it is important to have a sufficient amount of data in order for the model to give you good predictions over the testing set.

I hope this short explanation helped, if something isn't clear please let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: As I mentioned above **after convolution, the dimension of the activation map decreases and the depth increases.**. What do you say about this?

If I explain this a bit more, then I mean, after convolution with padding as **same** and stride as **1** ,  we'll get the output activation map of the same dimension as input is having. But after max pooling, the extracted feature will change its position, likewise in the end if I'll have activation map of 1x1 with depth N (suppose 512), then there won't be any use of the position. What is your opinion about this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good approach to train a model with **one background** (suppose white background) and test with **another background** (suppose grey background)?.

Background is a property of an image that is not required for distinguishing the object. You want your network to learn this behavior. Consider two cases now:

1. You give your network images with one background. Lets see what can go possibly wrong here.

   1. Assume that your background is completely black. This means that there will be 0 output for a feature map (kernel) when it was put into the background. Your network will learn that it can put any high weights for these features and it will do a good job during training as long as those weights can successfully extract feature of the classes.
   2. Now during testing, the background color is white. The same feature maps with high weight now will have very high output. These high output can saturate the non-linear unit and all categories may be classified as one category.
2. The second case where during training you shows images with different background.

   1. In this case, neural network has to learn that the feature maps corresponding to background and need to subtract the bias based on the background.

`In short, there is an extra information that you need to learn that is background is not important for deciding the category. When you provide only one color background, your neural network cannot learn this behavior and can give garbage result on test dataset.`

> Is it necessary or good approach to keep the object at different position while training the model?

You are right, Convolutional Neural Network are translational-equivariant. But for building a classifier, you pass the output of CNN-layer through a fully-connected layer. If you put image at different positions, different input will go to the fully-connected layer but  output for all these images is the same category. `So you are forcing your neural network to learn that the position of the object is not required for classifying its category.`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first doubt, It is not much of an issue as long as the target object is present in the images. Shuffle the data before feeding it to the network.

For second doubt, Yes it is always a good idea have target object at different positions. Also one more thing to take care is that the source of your data is same and mostly of same quality. Otherwise performance issue will arise.

Comment: Since I am keeping the background same for all the training set, it is not at all shuffled. Will the background not be considered as one of feature that convolution filter is going to extract?  If it will be considered as feature then it will affect the predict while testing.

And do you have any solid reason why **it is always a good idea have target object at different positions.**

Comment: 1/1  It is always a good idea to shuffle the train and val data irrespective of the variations, background and features present in images. In deep learning the CNN or any X algorithm's partial performance always depends on the data. Having the target object at different positions creates more variations of its representation which while training makes it hard for the model to memorize the training data upto some extent. Anyway at some point during training some representations of the training data is going to be memorized by the algorithm.

Comment: 1/2 This phenomena is called overfitting where the model performs well on training data but gives a poor performance on the validation and the test set.